# Why does my email shows up in Woocommerce check out page?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am newbie in Woocommerce.
I filled out profile information in WordPress "Customer Billing address" and "Customer Shipping address"
And when I checked the "Checkout" page, all my information was filled out.
So, I removed all my information which was in Profile, the information was gone in Checkout page. (Which is good!)
However, the email did not remove. (The profile states email is required, and whenever I go for checkout, my email shows up.) 
Can anyone know how to fix this problem?

Also, what plug-ins are there that if the customer buy multiple products and calculate the shipping costs at proceed to check out page?
For example, I want to set $9.45 for maximum weight/ dimension we set and if customer buy more products, I want to add percentage more for the weight/ dimension.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

**Hi happy to read your question .**

As you are seeing your profile details on checkout page because you are logged in your site as administrator so .

log out from your wordpress site then check checkout page

Regarding second issue you need add variable products in site or else  use below plugin - `http://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-shipping-calculator-on-product-page/11496815`